# for loop not carrying over parameter to next iteration

Tags: python

I've written something to calculate reserves where already reserved quantity needs to be taken into account in the next iteration. Only thing is the parameter isn;t used in the next iteration. The out put does contain the calculation, but the parameter isn't carried over. Any suggestions on how to solve this? Feel free to point out the muppetness of anything in the code, still learning

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('test_file.csv')

final_reserve = []


for i in range(len(df)):
    #If it's the first row or a new sku set the reserved to 0
    if i == 0 or df.loc[i]['SKU'] == df.loc[i-1]['SKU']:
        reserved = 0
        #calculate reserve
        to_reserve = df.loc[i]['ON_HAND'] - (df.loc[i]['SALES']*2) - df.loc[i]['ALREADY_RESERVED']
        final_reserve.append(to_reserve)
        #add to the reserved parameter
        reserved += to_reserve
    else:
        #if it's not the first row or a new sku take the already reserved units into account in the calculation
        to_reserve = df.loc[i]['ON_HAND'] - (df.loc[i]['SALES']*2) - df.loc[i]['ALREADY_RESERVED']-reserved
        final_reserve.append(to_reserve)
        reserved += to_reserve
df['to_reserve'] = final_reserve
df.head()
```

As the output shown below shows, on 2nd row it's getting to 500, where it should deduct the 300 already reserved on 1st row
[output reserve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXA11.png)

Comment: for the second row, are you expecting the code to flow through the "if" section, or the "else" section ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a quick look at your question, based on the first comment in your for loop:

```
#If it's the first row or a new sku set the reserved to 0
```

you want to change the next line to:

```
if i == 0 or df.loc[i]['SKU'] <> df.loc[i-1]['SKU']:
```

That is, change the second == operator to an <> operator.

As it stands now, your code is reseting the *reserved* to 0 if the SKU evaluated matches the previous one, and not if it is a new SKU.